# Why ping hop dest doesn't work?

Tags: ping

Why this would work in linux : `ping -I ens3 8.8.8.8` and not `ping 192.168.5.1 8.8.8.8` where `192.168.5.1` is the default gateway and so the next hop? In place I have a

```
permission denied: attempting raw socket
```

If you do `man ping` you will get the hop option nevertheless

Comment: Try again as root or with a suid binary.

Comment: for root it doesn't work at least on debian, ubuntu, archlinux. Going to try with suid later